How can I make sure my Java code is thread safe
I am trying to use SwingWorkers in my application (written in Java) where I collect some data from an API and display it in the app's GUI. Please keep in mind that I am very unsure when it comes to threads, it's a concept I struggle to grasp and understand.
I will provide the method for which the thread is being run.
    private void initialThread() {
        dataUpdateTimer = new Timer(60 * 60 * 1000, new ActionListener() { // Update every hour
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rg.getLoadingMsg(); // Display the JOptionPane message
                if (cachedChannelData != null) { //If the cached data is not null
                    cachedChannelData.clear(); //Clear the cached data to make new cache
                }
                rg.clearChannelTable(); //Clear the table displaying the channels (GUI)
                rg.clearGui(); //Clear the rest of the GUI
                SwingWorker<Void, Map<String, Map<String, programClass>>> sw = new SwingWorker<Void, Map<String, Map<String, programClass>>>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        cachedChannelData = cm.loadChannels(); //Get the channels (data retrieved from API)
                        publish(cachedChannelData); //Send the data that's been collected
                        return null; // Ensure doInBackground returns null as specified by its return type
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    protected void process(List<Map<String, Map<String, programClass>>> chunks) {

                        Map<String, Map<String, programClass>> result = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, programClass>> channelEntry : result.entrySet()) { //For every channel data retrieved from the API, do the following

                            String cname = cm.getChannelName(channelEntry.getKey()); //Get the channel's name
                            rg.displayChannels(cname, channelEntry.getKey()); //Add that channel to the table to display it
                            Map<String, programClass> programs = channelEntry.getValue(); //List of programs in that channel retrieved from the API
                            if(programs != null)
                            { //If there are programs in the channel, hence programs != null
                                for (Map.Entry<String, programClass> programEntry : programs.entrySet()) { //For every program in the channel
                                    programClass program = programEntry.getValue(); //Get a variable containing info about that program
                                    String description = program.getDescription(); // Get the description from the program
                                    JLabel image = program.getDisplayImage(); // Get the image JLabel from the program
                                    String start = program.getStart(); //Get the start time of the program
                                    String end = program.getEnd(); //Get the end time of the program
                                    String name = program.getName(); //Get the name of the program
                                    
                                    // Assuming you have a method to display each program's description and image individually
                                    rg.displayPrograms(description, image, name, start, end); // Display the programs
                                }
                                rg.clearGui(); //Clear the GUI of it's all old displayed data
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                };
                sw.execute(); 
            }
        });
    
        dataUpdateTimer.setInitialDelay(0); // Start timer immediately
        dataUpdateTimer.start();
    }

Here's the order in which I want my application to run:

Display a message (JOptionPane)
Clear the GUI
Collect the data
Display the data on screen


Concurrency in Swing

@Abra Yeah I've read the articles on oracle but, again, I really struggle with understanding threads, I would like to know what methods should I include the UI related stuff. I know process handles the data and presents it on the GUI, but other methods can I use to achieve this goal?

If you read the link (in my other comment), then you should know about methods addPropertyChangeListener and done (in class SwingWorker). In my opinion more appropriate for displaying task results in the GUI. Why did you decide to use methods publish and process? Is it because the SwingWorker will be run once every hour?

I've used publish to send the data collected and process to display the data in the GUI, it was to my understanding that this is the standard way of working with threads so I was following.

Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

What kind of Timer are you using?  Is it a Swing timer or a utils.timer?

This looks fine to me.  The potentially lengthy logic is in doInBackground, the Swing logic is in process.  I suppose since you’re only publishing once, you could do away with SwingWorker and call loadChannels in a new (preferably virtual) thread, and right after that call, place the Swing logic in an anonymous Runnable that gets passed to EventQueue.invokeLater.  It won’t perform differently, but it might be easier code to read.
